# Most robust way to fetch album art in Android

Tags: java, android, albumart

Please note that I have already been through similar questions and their answers here and on other websites. I also have a solution that works on some devices (my G2X running CyanogenMod 7.1, my wife's HD2 running a custom ROM and the emulator running Android 2.1). It doesn't, however work on my Nook running CyanogenMod.

My question is: What is the most robust and general way to fetch album art on all android devices? What are the gotchas for specific devices, versions or music applications (I don't mean third-party players, I mean Google Music versus the old Music client)? My current code is:

```
// Is this what's making my code fail on other devices?
public final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

// This works, and well on all devices
private int[] getAlbumIds(ContentResolver contentResolver)
{
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external"), new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            int albumId = cursor.getInt(0);
            if (!result.contains(albumId))
                result.add(albumId);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    int[] resultArray = new int[result.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        resultArray[i] = result.get(i);

    return resultArray;
}

// This is the bit I want to make more robust, make sure that it works on all devices
private Shader getAlbumArt(ContentResolver contentResolver, int albumId, int width, int height)
{
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
        if (input == null)
            return null;

        Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        input.close();
        if (artwork == null)
            return null;

        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(artwork, width, height, true);
        if (scaled == null)
            return null;

        if (scaled != artwork)
            artwork.recycle();
        artwork = scaled;

        return new BitmapShader(artwork, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Ananth

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here i can attach one function that is return album art from media store . Here in function we just have to pass the album_id which we get from Media store .

```
   public Bitmap getAlbumart(Long album_id) 
   {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try 
        {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);

            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

            if (pfd != null) 
            {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is the URI your code (and mine) uses always valid? Even on devices where there isn't an sdcard?

Comment: Here its takes uri only when sdcard is inserted in device.

Comment: Only downside is this requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
InputStream in = res.openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

More complete sample code can be found in Android Music player source here https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MusicUtils.java method getArtworkQuick.

Answer (score 0):

This below code snippet returns the uri for the album art cache present in the MediaStore. may be this will help.

```
            Cursor cursorAudio = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA}, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+ " LIKE \"" + path+ "\"", null, null);if(cursorAudio != null  && cursorAudio.moveToFirst()){
        Long albumId = Long.valueOf(cursorAudio.getString(cursorAudio.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)));
        cursorAudio.close();
        Cursor cursorAlbum = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=" + albumId, null, null);
        if(cursorAlbum != null  && cursorAlbum.moveToFirst()){
            String uri = cursorAlbum.getString(cursorAlbum.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
            cursorAlbum.close();
            if(uri != null){
                return Uri.parse(uri);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to modify Chirag Raval's answer by using Picasso library. It is simple to use and very powerful.

```
final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, arrayList.get(i).getArt());
    Picasso.with(context).load(uri).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(ivPic);
```

For full documentation, refer [this.](http://square.github.io/picasso/)